# I can't figure out why my makemigrations isn't working in django,its showing following error

Tags: python, mysql, django

here is my `models.py` file

```
from django.db import models



class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField("question",max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    #def __str__(self):
        #return self.question_text


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Here are the screenshots of errors

[Here is screenshot of my cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqbai.png)

Please help me to rectify this problem.

Comment: add a default value to choice_text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot it seems, you did select 2nd option but never really added the default value here.

It seems you already had `Choice` model and then later you added `choice_text` field. The database need to add this column in the choice table so either you provide a `default` value or you choose to go with `null=True`

Add a default value to `choice_field` in `Choice` model:

```
choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='your default value')
```

Or,

```
choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Your console says it clearly]

Your console clearly says,add some default value to choice_text field,this is happening because u may already have some data in Choice Model/Table and after migration when new non-nullable column is created ,it either wants to set default value from console or from python code :)